# Integrate Crypto++ in Android using Android.mk?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-ndk, crypto++

I want to integrate cryptopp module in my Android application. I tried but can not get any success and also not find any straight forward document or example for android.

Project structure : http://prntscr.com/n9g0k9

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            moduleName "cryptopp"
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] // This prevents the auto generation of Android.mk
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' // This is not necessary unless you have precompiled libraries in your project.
    }


    task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
        def ndkDir = android.ndkDirectory
        commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
                '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath, // Change src/main/jni the relative path to your jni source
                '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
                'all',
                'NDK_DEBUG=1'
    }

    task cleanNative(type: Exec, description: 'Clean JNI object files') {
        def ndkDir = android.ndkDirectory
        commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
                '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath, // Change src/main/jni the relative path to your jni source
                'clean'
    }

    clean.dependsOn 'cleanNative'

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn buildNative
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    /*externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }*/
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Android.mk

```
## Android.mk - Android build file for Crypto++. Written and placed in
##              public domain by Jeffrey Walton. Based on Android.mk
##              by Alex Afanasyev (GitHub @cawka),
##              https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/pull/3
##
##              The Android make uses GNU Make and is documented at
##              https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk
##              The CPU Features library is documented at
##              https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpu-features
##
##              You can create the list of files below with:
##
##                  $ make sources | fold -w74 -s
##

## TODO - We use this line below in the .mk file:
##            LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/..
## The open question is, should we be exporting the path as:
##            LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(CRYPTOPP_PATH)

ifeq ($(NDK_LOG),1)
    $(info Crypto++: TARGET_ARCH: $(TARGET_ARCH))
    $(info Crypto++: TARGET_PLATFORM: $(TARGET_PLATFORM))
endif

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

#####################################################################
# Adjust CRYPTOPP_PATH to suit your taste, like ../cryptopp-7.1/.
# If CRYPTOPP_PATH is empty then it means the library files and the
# Android files are side-by-side in the same directory. If
# CRYPTOPP_PATH is not empty then must include the trailing slash.
# The trailing slash is needed because CRYPTOPP_PATH is prepended
# to each source file listed in CRYPTOPP_SRC_FILES.

# CRYPTOPP_PATH ?= ../cryptopp/
CRYPTOPP_PATH ?=

ifeq ($(NDK_LOG),1)
  ifeq ($CRYPTOPP_PATH),)
    $(info Crypto++: CRYPTOPP_PATH is empty)
  else
    $(info Crypto++: CRYPTOPP_PATH is $(CRYPTOPP_PATH))
  endif
endif

#####################################################################
# Library source files

CRYPTOPP_SRC_FILES := \
    cryptlib.cpp cpu.cpp integer.cpp 3way.cpp adler32.cpp algebra.cpp login_connection.cpp \
    algparam.cpp arc4.cpp aria_simd.cpp aria.cpp ariatab.cpp asn.cpp \
    authenc.cpp base32.cpp base64.cpp basecode.cpp bfinit.cpp \
    blake2.cpp blowfish.cpp blumshub.cpp camellia.cpp cast.cpp casts.cpp \
    cbcmac.cpp ccm.cpp chacha_simd.cpp chacha.cpp cham_simd.cpp cham.cpp \
    channels.cpp cmac.cpp crc_simd.cpp crc.cpp default.cpp des.cpp dessp.cpp \
    dh.cpp dh2.cpp dll.cpp dsa.cpp eax.cpp ec2n.cpp eccrypto.cpp ecp.cpp \
    elgamal.cpp emsa2.cpp eprecomp.cpp esign.cpp files.cpp filters.cpp \
    fips140.cpp fipstest.cpp gcm_simd.cpp gcm.cpp gf256.cpp gf2_32.cpp \
    gf2n.cpp gfpcrypt.cpp gost.cpp gzip.cpp hc128.cpp hc256.cpp hex.cpp \
    hight.cpp hmac.cpp hrtimer.cpp ida.cpp idea.cpp iterhash.cpp kalyna.cpp \
    kalynatab.cpp keccak.cpp lea_simd.cpp lea.cpp luc.cpp mars.cpp \
    marss.cpp md2.cpp md4.cpp md5.cpp misc.cpp modes.cpp mqueue.cpp mqv.cpp \
    nbtheory.cpp neon_simd.cpp oaep.cpp osrng.cpp padlkrng.cpp panama.cpp \
    pkcspad.cpp poly1305.cpp polynomi.cpp ppc_simd.cpp pssr.cpp pubkey.cpp \
    queue.cpp rabbit.cpp rabin.cpp randpool.cpp rc2.cpp rc5.cpp rc6.cpp \
    rdrand.cpp rdtables.cpp rijndael_simd.cpp rijndael.cpp ripemd.cpp rng.cpp \
    rsa.cpp rw.cpp safer.cpp salsa.cpp scrypt.cpp seal.cpp seed.cpp \
    serpent.cpp sha_simd.cpp sha.cpp sha3.cpp shacal2_simd.cpp shacal2.cpp \
    shark.cpp sharkbox.cpp simeck_simd.cpp simeck.cpp simon.cpp \
    simon128_simd.cpp simon64_simd.cpp skipjack.cpp sm3.cpp sm4_simd.cpp \
    sm4.cpp sosemanuk.cpp speck.cpp speck128_simd.cpp speck64_simd.cpp \
    square.cpp squaretb.cpp sse_simd.cpp strciphr.cpp tea.cpp tftables.cpp \
    threefish.cpp tiger.cpp tigertab.cpp ttmac.cpp tweetnacl.cpp twofish.cpp \
    vmac.cpp wake.cpp whrlpool.cpp xtr.cpp xtrcrypt.cpp zdeflate.cpp \
    zinflate.cpp zlib.cpp

#####################################################################
# Test source files

# Remove adhoc.cpp from this list

CRYPTOPP_TEST_FILES := \
    test.cpp bench1.cpp bench2.cpp bench3.cpp datatest.cpp \
    dlltest.cpp fipsalgt.cpp validat0.cpp validat1.cpp validat2.cpp \
    validat3.cpp validat4.cpp validat5.cpp validat6.cpp validat7.cpp \
    validat8.cpp validat9.cpp validat10.cpp regtest1.cpp regtest2.cpp \
    regtest3.cpp regtest4.cpp

#####################################################################
# ARM A-32 source file

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH),arm)
    CRYPTOPP_SRC_FILES += aes_armv4.S
    LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
    LOCAL_FILTER_ASM :=
endif

#####################################################################
# Shared object

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := cryptopp_shared
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(addprefix $(CRYPTOPP_PATH),$(CRYPTOPP_SRC_FILES))
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -Wall
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES := rtti exceptions
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL -Wl,--as-needed

LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := $(LOCAL_CFLAGS)
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/..

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cpufeatures

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#####################################################################
# Static library

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := cryptopp_static
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(addprefix $(CRYPTOPP_PATH),$(CRYPTOPP_SRC_FILES))
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -Wall
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES := rtti exceptions

LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := $(LOCAL_CFLAGS)
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/..

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cpufeatures

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

#####################################################################
# Test program

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := cryptest.exe
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(addprefix $(CRYPTOPP_PATH),$(CRYPTOPP_TEST_FILES))
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -Wall
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES := rtti exceptions
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -Wl,--as-needed

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cryptopp_static
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

#####################################################################
# Android cpuFeatures library

$(call import-module,android/cpufeatures)
```

Application.mk

```
## Application.mk - Android build file for Crypto++. Written and placed
##            in public domain by Jeffrey Walton. Based on
##            Application.mk by Alex Afanasyev (GitHub @cawka),
##            https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/pull/3
##
##            The Android make uses GNU Make and is documented at
##            https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk
##
##            For a list of Android Platforms and API levels see
##            https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis
##            Android 4.3 is android-18, and Android 5 is android-21.
##
##            Android recommends c++_shared for NDK version 16.0 and
##            above. Android will be removing other runtime libraries
##            as early as NDK version 18. Also see
##            https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.

APP_ABI := all
APP_PLATFORM := android-21

# APP_STL := gnustl_shared
APP_STL := c++_shared

CRYPTOPP_ROOT := $(call my-dir)
NDK_PROJECT_PATH := $(CRYPTOPP_ROOT)
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := $(CRYPTOPP_ROOT)/Android.mk

GREP ?= grep
NDK_r16_OR_LATER := $(shell $(GREP) -i -c -E "Pkg.Revision = (1[6-9]|[2-9][0-9]\.)" "$$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/source.properties")
ifneq ($(NDK_r16_OR_LATER),0)
  ifneq ($(APP_STL),c++_shared)
    $(info Crypto++: NDK r16 or later. Use c++_shared instead of $(APP_STL))
  endif
endif

ifeq ($(NDK_LOG),1)
    $(info Crypto++: ANDROID_NDK_ROOT is $(ANDROID_NDK_ROOT))
    $(info Crypto++: NDK_PROJECT_PATH is $(NDK_PROJECT_PATH))
    $(info Crypto++: APP_BUILD_SCRIPT is $(APP_BUILD_SCRIPT))
endif

ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),debug) # template for conditional rules
   C_SOURCE_FILES += uart.c
endif
```

And below is command i execute in terminal

```
:cryptopp user$ ndk-build V=1 NDK_PROJECT_PATH="$PWD" NDK_APPLICATION_MK="$PWD/Application.mk"
```

Comment: Have you tried using this: https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-android ?

Comment: _"I tried but can not get any success"_ You haven't shown us what you tried, so we can't possibly know what you did wrong.

Comment: I already follow this document and tried to build it but not getting success

Comment: let me share you. @Michael

Comment: @Michael : just update my question please look in to this.

Comment: @Michael : have you getting chance to look into this?

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is with the makefiles you've posted.

Comment: @Mehul - You need to state the problem or the error. I think one of the problems is, the filelist in `CRYPTOPP_SRC_FILES` is old/stale. Regenerate the list using a Linux host. Do so by typing `make sources`. It will list the source files for the library. The bigger problem is, AOSP changed their toolchain again and we have not had time to fix the breaks. The changes completely broke `setenv-android.sh`. We added `Android.mk` in hopes that it would be more resilient to toolchain changes.

Comment: @jww : Thanks for update. Its because of i am totally beginner in cryptopp. Even i don't know how to compile this. I follow steps from  github.com/noloader/cryptopp-android and try to build it. If possible then suggest good document or example that use above library.

Comment: @jww Thanks for update. Can i know can we integrate Crypto++ in android? Means Android support Crypto++ compiler vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to integrate cryptopp module in my Android application. I tried but can not get any success and also not find any straight forward document or example for android.

The documents you are looking for are on the [Crypto++ wiki](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki) at [Android Setup (Command Line)](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Android_Setup_(Command_Line)#Env_Variables) and [Android.mk (Command Line)](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Android.mk_(Command_Line)). The first wiki article tells you how to setup an Android build machine. Or maybe more correctly, how Crypto++ sets up an Android build machine for testing. The second wiki article tells you how to build with `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` given you have an Android build machine.

When I perform the build using the wiki articles I see:

```
cryptopp$ ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH="$PWD" NDK_APPLICATION_MK="$PWD/Application.mk"
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= test.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= bench1.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= bench2.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= bench3.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= datatest.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= dlltest.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= fipsalgt.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= validat0.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= validat1.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= validat2.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= validat3.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= validat4.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= validat5.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= validat6.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= validat7.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= validat8.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= validat9.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= validat10.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= regtest1.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= regtest2.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= regtest3.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptest.exe <= regtest4.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Prebuilt       : libc++_shared.so <= <NDK>/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a/
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptopp_static <= cryptlib.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptopp_static <= cpu.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptopp_static <= integer.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptopp_static <= 3way.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptopp_static <= adler32.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptopp_static <= algebra.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptopp_static <= algparam.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptopp_static <= arc4.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptopp_static <= aria_simd.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptopp_static <= aria.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptopp_static <= ariatab.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptopp_static <= asn.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : cryptopp_static <= authenc.cpp
...
```

Given enough time and disk space, `ndk-build` will build all the Android architectures.

I don't know how to use Kotlin or other build systems like Maven. I don't use them, so I can't help you if your problem lies there.

I think you need to state the errors you are encountering so folks know how to help you.

---

***Note***: `cryptopp-android` previously lacked tags that followed Crypto++ releases. We fixed that tonight, but only going back to Crypto++ 7.0. You should ensure you download the [`cryptopp-android` release](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-android/releases) that corresponds to the Crypto++ release you are using. They use the same tags, like `CRYPTOPP_7_0_0`, `CRYPTOPP_8_0_0` and `CRYPTOPP_8_1_0`. Master should roughly follow master on both projects.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try and update you. Thanks once again for your time.